# Get every algorithm MessageDigest can use?

Tags: android, hash

`MessageDigest` takes a string for what algorithm to use when you're about to hash. [I've used some of the code here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/ListServices.html) to accumulate a rather large list of 220 "algorithms" on my android device. I iterated through all of them using them as an algorithm in `MessageDigest` and very few of them actually produce a hash.

How can I, at runtime, determine what hashes `MessageDigest` will produce an output for without trying every one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List the [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Provider.Service.html) of each provider, then call the `getType()` method. If it is `MessageDigest`, then this is a hash algorithm. Something like:

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for (Provider p : providers) {
  String providerStr = String.format("%s/%s/%f\n", p.getName(),
                    p.getInfo(), p.getVersion());
  Set<Service> services = p.getServices();
  for (Service s : services) {
    if ("MessageDigest".equals(s.getType())) {
       System.out.printf("\t%s/%s/%s", s.getType(),
                            s.getAlgorithm(), s.getClassName());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Complementing, the Java specification requires every MessageDigest to support at least the MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256 algorithms. (Font: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)

Comment: Android does not confirm to any Oracle specifications :)