# Using SHA2 to encrypt a password field

Tags: android

What is the best way to implement SHA2 in an Android application which supports 2.3 & more ? The best way to save a text SHA2 encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use **MessageDigest** from java.security package with "SHA-256" algorithm: 
   http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Example code:

```
public byte[] digest(String value) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] stringBytes = value.getBytes();

    digester.update(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.length);

    return digester.digest();
}
```

This method will return a digest of a given string as byte array or throw NoSuchAlgorithmException in case SHA-256 isn't supported on the device.

To get the list of available algorithms you can use with MessageDigest: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12851438/4183841

2. Another option is to use a port of **BouncyCastle** for Android:
   http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/

BuncyCastle documentation for SHA 256 digest: 
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA256Digest.html

This option will work on all devices, but you will have to include a port of BouncyCastle library in your application.

Comment: Is SHA-2 & SHA-256 same ? My understanding is, SHA-2 consists of various hashing algorithms & SHA-256 is one among them & this is good to implement in Android. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: That's right, SHA-2 consists of various algorithms that can produce digests of different lengths: 224, 256, 384 or 512 bits. I don't know what is your use case, but SHA-256 is probably secure enough.